# Fluid Sim/Rigid body issues

Tags: fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

I should probably start out by saying that I am fairly new to Blender.

So I am trying to create just a simple ball rolling down some platforms while emitting water that interacts with the platforms.

I have gotten the rigid body to work with the ball rolling down the platforms, but the fluid sim is just not working at all and I don't know why. I thought that I had set everything up correctly as I have been trying to learn fluid sims for a while, but nothing ever works

Please help

[image: What is happening when I bake]

Comment: Huh your fluid is outside your domain? That is interesting, can you in any case share your file so I can look at it?

Comment: Yes. When I figure out how to share it

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ here you go

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jyo7Godl" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jyo7Godl/)